# What is the plain form (普通形) of どうでした? Is it どうだった or just どう? And is the plain form of Vてください just て?

Tags: form

How do I turn interrogatives into plain form?

What is the plain form (普通けい) of どうでした? Is it どうだった or just どう? And is the plain form of Vてください just て?

Comment: How do you plan to use the plain form of V-てください?

Comment: *Plain forms* (普通形) refer to certain inflected forms of verbs or adjectives with particular grammatical functions. Are you asking about those, or do you want to know how to say どうでした and V-てください in plain spoken style?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. どうでした?
> 2. どうだった?
>
> How was it? / Did it go well?

Yes, Sentence 2 is an informal/casual equivalent of 1. Just saying "どう?" would change the meaning ("How is it? / Is it going well?") because it lacks the past marker (た).

> 1. 見てください。
> 2. 見て。
>
> (Please) look!

Sentence 1 is a polite request and Sentence 2 is an informal request. However, I think "form" is not the right word to describe this difference, because this ください is basically a distinct subsidiary verb added after the main verb. These are just two different patterns of making a request in Japanese, and neither is a different "form" of the other. There are other ways of making a request with different nuances (見な, 見てちょうだい, 見てくれ, 見ていただけませんか, ご覧なさい, ご覧あれ, ...), just as English has many ways of making a request with different politeness levels, including "Please ...", "Would you mind if you...", "Can you ...". (EDIT: You can use "polite/plain *style*" or "polite/informal *style*" to distinguish those two expressions.)

Comment: On this being an issue about "form": I think most sources I have seen juxtapose 「ください」(丁寧形) with 「て形」(普通形) (e.g. [1](http://jn2et.com/Kyouan/L20.html) and [2](https://study.u-biq.org/memo47.html)). The best definition of 普通形 I have heard was 「丁寧な要素だけを抜いた形」

Comment: @EddieKal I hesitate to call 食べてください a "form" of 食べる in the first place, for the same reason why *please eat* is not a "form" of *eat*. Does 食べてください have a common name as a form?

Comment: I believe 食べてください is considered 丁寧形. I am not sure the comparison with English is a reasonable one. English verbs are lacking in conjugations. And English learners wouldn't be asked to change a text from "polite form" to "plain form". But that's a very common exercise in Japanese teaching, I believe.

Comment: @EddieKal The 丁寧形 of that verb is 食べます, not 食べてください. Besides, syntactically speaking, the closest "plain" equivalent of 食べてください should be 食べてくれ, even if it's a bit less useful than 食べて. (What "form" is 食べてくれ?) From a practical point of view, it's OK to think of 食べてください and 食べて as a "pair", but from a grammatical point of view, it's not as simple as the 食べました-食べた pair.

Comment: @EddieKal - But your links do distinguish 普通**形** and 普通**体**. The former refers to conjugation forms of a **word** such as 食べる (non-past affirmative), 食べない (non-past negative), 食べた (past affirmative), and 食べなかった (past negative). 食べてください is not a word.